# Serialize collection of objects with one value using RestSharp

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, restsharp

I need the next xml data:

```
<trackingrequest>
    <user>USERNAME</user>
    <password>PASSWORD</password>
    <trackingnumbers>
        <trackingnumber>12345678901</trackingnumber>
    </trackingnumbers>
</trackingrequest>
```

For this purposes I have created the next models:

```
[SerializeAs(Name = "trackingrequest")]
public class DpdTrackingRequest
{
    [SerializeAs(Name = "user")]
    public string User { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "trackingnumbers")]
    [XmlArrayItem("trackingnumber")]
    public IList<DpdTrackingNumber> TrackingNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class DpdTrackingNumber
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

But when I call `AddXmlBody` method I see the next result:

```
<trackingrequest>
    <user>USERNAME</user>
    <password>PASSWORD</password>
    <trackingnumbers>
        <DpdTrackingNumber>
            <Value>12345678901</Value>
        </DpdTrackingNumber>
    </trackingnumbers>
</trackingrequest>
```

How can I combine `<DpdTrackingNumber><Value>12345678901</Value></DpdTrackingNumber>` in `<trackingnumber>12345678901</trackingnumber>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve your requirement, I think you have to set `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute` to `DpdTrackingNumber.Value` property.


However, `RestRequest`'s `XmlSerializer` is `RestSharp.Serializers.XmlSerializer` as default and it cannot read `System.Xml.Serialization` attributes.

Therefore, you have to reset the `XmlSerializer` to `RestSharp.Serializers.DotNetXmlSerializer` before calling `AddXmlBody` method.

```
dpdTrackingRequest.TrackingNumbers = new List<DpdTrackingNumber>();
dpdTrackingRequest.TrackingNumbers.Add(new DpdTrackingNumber { Value = "12345678901" });

RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest();
// reset XmlSerializer
restRequest.XmlSerializer = new RestSharp.Serializers.DotNetXmlSerializer();
var result = restRequest.AddXmlBody(dpdTrackingRequest);
```

Also, you may have to change the type of `TrackingNumbers` from `IList` to `List` as `DotNetXmlSerializer` cannot seriralize interfaces so `DpdTrackingRequest` class is as follows:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

//was [SerializeAs(Name = "trackingrequest")]
[XmlRoot("trackingrequest")]
public class DpdTrackingRequest
{
    //was [SerializeAs(Name = "user")]
    [XmlElement("user")]
    public string User { get; set; }

    //was [SerializeAs(Name = "password")]
    [XmlElement("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    //was [SerializeAs(Name = "trackingnumbers")]
    //from IList to List
    [XmlArray("trackingnumbers")]
    [XmlArrayItem("trackingnumber")]
    public List<DpdTrackingNumber> TrackingNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class DpdTrackingNumber
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```